# Android Timer/CountDownTimer execute on onResume(

Tags: android, timer

I'm doing a small android application. I want that when the application stops, a timer or a countdowntimer is launched, and after a time (30 seconds) it executes an action, in my case closing connection with a server.
This works perfectly, the problem is that when you resume the application, the timer/countdowntimer is launched again, and I do not want that.

this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    desconexionTimer = new Timer();
    desconexionTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ThreadDesconexion(this).execute();
        }
    }, 30 * 1000);

} 

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    if(!ConexionServer.threIsConexion()){
         comeActivityLogin();
     }  
}
```

I try use a CountDownTimer and happen the same.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              Log.d("INFO","HELLO");
          }

          public void onFinish() {
              new ThreadDesconexion(this).execute()     }
   }.start();
}
```

I'm doing something wrong? or there's some way to do this?
thank you very much

Comment: Need to add confition in onStop to call or not CountDownTimer(...)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call the comeActivityLogin() in your onResume() method you start a new activity and because of activity lifecycle the onStop() method is called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Include onpause() before onResume() method with the following code...

```
public long pause() {
  mPauseTime = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
  mPaused = true;
return mPauseTime;
}


public long resume() {
    mStopTimeInFuture = mPauseTime + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    mPaused = false;
    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
  return mPauseTime;
}
```

check this link for more code...
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-countdowntimer-start-pause.html